# help finding n-th partial sum ... of converging sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

need help finding the nth partial sum of

1 + 2(1/2) + 3(1/4) + 4(1/8) + 5(1/16) + 6(1/32) + 7(1/64) + ... +x(1/2^(x-1)) + ...

converges by the ratio test

Thanks

Comment: You know the geometric sum? Differentiate it.

Comment: Hint: compute $S-\dfrac S2$ term-wise.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks ... I noticed S1 = 1, S2 = 2, S3 = 2 + 3/4, S4 = 2 + 10/8, S5 = 2 + 25/16 ... but get no where ...

Comment: @RobinsonKevin-Becky: this is unrelated to my hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k2^{1-k}-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty k2^{1-k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k2^{1-k}-\sum_{k=2}^\infty(k-1)2^{1-k}=1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty2^{1-k}=2.$$